# How to distinguish installation of ArcView from ArcEditor?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, standard-license-level, basic-license-level

How would I tell an installation of ArcView from ArcEditor, if looking at only the installed files? Specifically, how do I distinguish

- ArcView 9.3 from ArcEditor 9.3
- ArcView 10.0 from ArcEditor 10.0

For example, the file ArcSOC.exe indicates an installation of ArcGIS Server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The installs are the same.
If you go to desktop administrator and select the software product folder
you will see the options to switch between licensed products.

If you are using an ESRI network license you can change this setting readily.

If you are on a standalone you will only have the choice to use it or switch to a floating license.

In which case you would need to supply a license server.

Answer (score 5):

My understanding is that the install files are the same between licensing levels. When installing you do not choose which licensing level to install. Available features are then determined by activation through the license manager.